# ElasticSearch should/must clause not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest, elasticsearch-marvel

Below is my elastic query

```
 GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "marriages.marriage_year": "1630"
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "match": {
          "first_name": {
            "query": "mary",
            "fuzziness": "2"
          }
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "marriages.marriage_year": {
            "gt": "1620",
            "lte": "1740"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is returning data with `marriages.marriage_year= "1630"` with Mary as first_name as highest score.I also want to include `marriages.marriage_year` between 1620 - 1740 which are not shown in the results. It is showing data only for `marriage_year` 1630

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have two `bool/must` clauses and the second one gets eliminated when the JSON query is parsed. Rewrite it like this instead and it will work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "marriages.marriage_year": "1630"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "marriages.marriage_year": {
              "gt": "1620",
              "lte": "1740"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": {
        "match": {
          "first_name": {
            "query": "mary",
            "fuzziness": "2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Then you need to do it differently and in the `bool/must` you need to have only the `range` query and move the `match` inside the `bool/should` section:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "marriages.marriage_year": {
              "gt": "1620",
              "lte": "1740"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "first_name": {
              "query": "mary",
              "fuzziness": "2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "marriages.marriage_year": "1630"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried above query it is still returning only marriage_year related to 1630.

Comment: This one is perfect. Thanks